# Configuring vimdiff splits with specific statusline / line-numbers

Tags: git, vim, git-merge, vimdiff, mergetool

I'm trying to set up `git mergetool` to spawn `vimdiff` with the following splits (and *a configuration customized to each split*):

- <s>Splits from the following buffers $LOCAL, $BASE, $REMOTE, & $MERGED (horizontal)</s> [*done*]
- Show line-numbers per split [*Todo*]
- Display *only* the name of the buffer variable in these three splits: $LOCAL, $BASE, $REMOTE. [*Todo*]
- <s>The $MERGED split statusline should show the filename from `%t` [the $MERGED split is done]</s>

I used this git configuration in my local repo:

```
git config merge.tool vimdiff
git config mergetool.vimdiff.cmd 'vim +"set number" +"set statusline=%t" -d -c "wincmd J" -O $MERGED $BASE $REMOTE $LOCAL'
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
git config mergetool.prompt false
```

- In the configuration above, a status line substring should be displayed per-split but I can't find the right way to build a regex to reduce the filename in the statusline down to just one of the three desired buffer variable names (i.e. "BASE", "REMOTE", or "LOCAL").  A regex isn't required, but it seems like a promising option.
- Line numbers are only showing up in one split, but I want them in all four.

After much googling and many experiments, I still can't coerce `vimdiff` into showing the status line / numbers I want... I am not using a statusline plugin such as vim-powerline.  How do I configure my git options to spawn `vimdiff` the way I need?

I included a screen capture of my existing `git mergetool` splits.

[image: vimdiff_4_panes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Adding line numbers for every split

In this command,`vim +"set number" ... -O $MERGED $BASE $REMOTE $LOCAL`, looks like vim intenally first creates the splits and then executes the set option. Refer: [vim -c option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-c).

There are 2 options to overcome this.

1. **Use `--cmd` option:** If we use, `vim --cmd "set number" -O $MERGED $BASE $REMOTE $LOCAL`, `set number` is applied before creating the splits. In fact, it is applied even before reading the .vimrc file. (Refer: [vim --cmd option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#--cmd)). It might cause concern if we have a overriding config in .vimrc like `set nonumber`.
2. **Create splits manually:** Instead of `-O` option, we can manually create the splits. This way after the `-c` option is applied, the splits will be created. We will send the file parameters in the reverse order as below:

   ```
   vim +"set number" +"vs $LOCAL" +"vs $BASE" +"vs $MERGED" +"wincmd J" $REMOTE
   ```

   But now we need another option (`diff this`) to enable `diff` in all splits, since `-d` only applies to the files passed directly in the command line.

   ```
   vim +"set number" +"vs $LOCAL" +"vs $BASE" +"vs $MERGED" +"wincmd J" +"windo 
   diffthis" $REMOTE
   ```

#### Modifying the status line

Rather than regex, using static strings looks a more reliable option. We can leverage vim `setlocal` options to acheive this. So the total command will be

```
vim +"set number" +"setlocal statusline=REMOTE" +"vs $LOCAL" +"setlocal statusline=LOCAL" +"vs $BASE" +"setlocal statusline=BASE" +"vs $MERGED" +"wincmd J" +"windo diffthis" $REMOTE
```

**Git mergetool config:**

```
git config merge.tool vimdiff
git config mergetool.vimdiff.cmd 'vim +"set number" +"setlocal statusline=REMOTE" +"vs $LOCAL" +"setlocal statusline=LOCAL" +"vs $BASE" +"setlocal statusline=BASE" +"vs $MERGED" +"wincmd J" +"windo diffthis" $REMOTE'
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
git config mergetool.prompt false
```

**`git mergetool` output:**
[image: git mergetool output]

---

#### Update 1

If it is ok to retain the existing status line or do a simple append of the buffer number of the split, then `-S` vim option can be used to greatly simplify the command.

```
git config mergetool.vimdiff.cmd 'vim -d -S "~/.git_merge_vimrc" -O $MERGED $BASE $REMOTE $LOCAL
```

**`.git_merge_vimrc` contents:**

```
set statusline=%t-Split#%n
wincmd J
windo set number
```

*Note:* vim scripts can be used in the source file to print complex status line if that is required.
[image: git mergetool output(with sourcefile)]

Comment: I truly wish there was a better way to configure `mergetool.vimdiff.cmd` because by removing the `vim -O` option we now have so many different `--cmd` options that vim throws `Too many "+command", "-c command" or "--cmd command" arguments` if I try adding **any** other `+"set foo"` options.

Comment: Also, I tweaked your vimdiff command a bit... I settled on: `vim +"set number" +"setlocal statusline=\$REMOTE-Split_#3" +"vs $LOCAL" +"setlocal statusline=\$LOCAL-Split_#2" +"vs $BASE" +"setlocal statusline=\$BASE-Split_#1" +"vs $MERGED" +"wincmd J" +"setlocal statusline=%t-Split_#4" +"windo diffthis" $REMOTE` for now

Comment: @MikePennington, please check if the Update suits your use case better. The status line might vary from your expectation. I am using the buffer no to suffix and the no is based on the order given in `-O` option.

Comment: The results in [my first comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527864/configuring-vimdiff-splits-with-specific-statusline-line-numbers/64534134?noredirect=1#comment114118634_64534134) are better... I definitely need to know what buffer is LOCAL, REMOTE, or BASE.  So, realistically we might not be able to get rid of all the individual vim CLI commands but I wish we could